# EWS API not returning display name for Guest user for MS Teams conversation

Tags: exchangewebservices, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using EWS Managed API v2.2 to access MS Teams messages (from the folder: Top of Information Store->Conversation History-> Team Chat). The API result contains sender, recipient, message body, message date time. It was working great so far until guest user does not come into picture.

From MS Teams, we can invite guest user. We send meeting invitation to a guest user (any user like gmail account). Then, guest user will receive email with the invitation link. When he clicks, he will just need to provide display name and then he can enter into chat and can send and receives message in MS Team in browser.

Now, when we capture the conversation where guest user is part of; using EWS API. We are seeing following two behaviors from the EWS API result:
Guest user "sent message" has just Display name in the sender field.
Guest user "received message" has just user id like 8:teamsvisitor:0e47ccce7ee34a2683815e4070015a54 in the recipients field.

In general, we used to get user email address and display name for normal users in both sender and recipients fields. For guest users, we are seeing inconsistent in sent and received.

Now, my question is: 
 1. Does EWS API has any other work around to fetch both id and display name for guest user.

We are also looking if there is any MS Graph API to find display name using that user id but have not found any so far.

Comment: The guest user account is not under AAD (guest user is not a user from a different tenant whose account is under AAD. I can tell that the identifier format is different from OID and entering name would not be required).
It looks like there's a service that creates temporary user account for anonymous users (with id 8:teamsvisitor:xxx). Is there a lookup service that needs to be used here to translate this into a display name? (I don't think EWS can do this.)